# How to Calculate Hex offset locations in a file

Tags: binary, hex, byte, offset, hexdump

How do I calculate the byte location of the hex offset 326a f338 (little endian) in a file. Struggling to understand how this is calculated. The steps I tried were:

1. Convert to Little Endian: 833f a623
2. Convert 833f and a623 to decimal: 833f = 33599 And a623 = 42531
3. Subtract the 2 values: 42531 - 33599 = 8,932

According to this calculation the location of the hex offset of 326a f338 would be the 8,932 byte of the file. This doesn't work because there aren't that many bytes in the file. Can someone explain to me what part of my calculation is incorrect?

Comment: You reverse the bytes, which are two nibbles each, not the nibbles when converting between big and little endian. One nibble = 4 bits, one byte = 8 bits. So the little endian version would be 38 f3 6a 32. This is 955476530 in decimal, which would mean the file is almost a gigabyte. Given that you say the file is less than 8KB, you probably want to provide more information (like how do you know that the hex offset you got is valid?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not converting from little-endian to big-endian correctly. If you have 4 bytes in little-endian which are 326af338, then your big-endian representation is 38f36a32.

Endian-ness is the direction in which you serialize the bytes. Little endian means least significant bytes sent/stored first, big endian means most significant bytes sent/stored first.

Converting from one representation to the other on paper requires "reading" the bytes in the opposite direction. A byte, in hex representation is 2 digits, so you read your little-endian hex number backwards 2 digits at a time to get your big-endian hex number.

So your offset is 0x38f36a32 in base 16, which has a decimal representation in base 10 of 955476530.

Reading up from a file/stream, and reading at that offset is going to depend on your IO library.

Comment: Thank you for the help mipnw and Ross Jacobs. Both of you were right, I was converting to little endian wrong which was giving me the wrong results.